# How to send multiple post parameters using require('request');

Tags: node.js, http-post

In this snippet I'm attempting to send a url parameter as part of body in post request :

```
var request = require('request');

  request.post({
     headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
     url : 'http://localhost:7777',
     body : 'tosummarise='+data+'&url'+url
    },
```

but `&url` parameter is not being set. Is this correct method of sending multiple post parameters in `request.post` ? The `tosummarise` value is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I omitted the `=` in request param. This code works :

```
var request = require('request');

  request.post({
     headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
     url : 'http://localhost:7777',
     body : 'tosummarise='+data+'&url='+url
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your 'body' here should be part of your URL instead. actual POST body data goes into 'body'